# How Can I activate virtual environment in wsl in pycharm while using debug mode of a script (Linux machine)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pipenv

Note: I am using pipenv and wsl in windows

While in debug mode virtual environment is not activated than script is not running properly

I tried multiple ways in Settings -> Terminal

and Run -> Edit configuration But script is not running in virtual environment in debug mode

Pycharm : 2022

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to set your project interpreter as the WSL type and point it at your `virtualenv/bin/python`

[image]

Comment: Yes sir , I have already did this steps ... But it couldn't help